# What does this equation mean?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an exam tomorrow and I was trying to solve my Homework questions. I am stuck at this question:

Find the general solution of the equation
$$tdy + ydt = 3t^3y^2dt$$

It was exactly written as above. I am confused.

I can get $df(x)/dx$, take the derivative of $f(x)$ one time acording to $x$ or when you write $dx$ with an $\int$ sign as $\int$$dx$. Can I use $dx$ alone? Can I simplify above equation by dividing both sides by $dt$? Does $df(x)$ has a meaning alone?

Comment: This equation is separable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: This is a first-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation, let

$$y = v t \rightarrow y' = v + v' t$$

This is also Bernoulli's equation.

Comment: Short and sweet it is! +1